# Matplotlib x-axis at the top, no x axis label, no major tick labels, but outer major and minor tick wanted

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to plot a plot with a an upper x-axis without the labeling, but including the major and minor ticks.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns

perf = np.cumprod(1+np.random.normal(size=250)/100)
df = pd.DataFrame({'underwater': perf/np.maximum.accumulate(perf)-1})


sns.set_context('notebook')
sns.set_style('ticks', rc = {'axes.grid': True, 'axes.spines.left': True, 'axes.spines.right': False, 'axes.spines.bottom': True, 'axes.spines.top': False})

ax = plt.gca()
df.plot.area(ax=ax, label = 'underwater')
ax.xaxis.tick_top()
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
sns.despine(left=False, bottom=True, right=True, top = False, ax=ax)
```

[image]
I am missing the major (outside) x-axis ticks at the top.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the last line to your code. Moreover, you do not need the `tick_top()` line

```
ax = plt.gca()
df.plot.area(ax=ax, label = 'underwater')
# ax.xaxis.tick_top() # <----- This line is not needed
ax.xaxis.set_ticklabels([])
sns.despine(left=False, bottom=True, right=True, top = False, ax=ax)

# Add the following line to your code
ax.tick_params('x', length=8, width=2, color='red',  which='major', direction='out')
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for the help! That is exactly what I was looking for!